# Can we name a class with a Java keyword?

Tags: java, class

What happens if we use a Java key word as our class name. In my case I created a class "Process". But I can not instantiate it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: "Process" is not a keyword

Comment: This is a list of Java keywords: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use Java keywords as identifiers in a Java program (to name a class, or a variable for example). However, you did not use a Java keyword, rather you named your class `Process` just like the `java.lang.Process` class. Since the `java.lang.*` package is imported by default in any java class, that is why you cannot instantiate it.

If you really want to instantiate your own `Process` class just refer to it with its fully qualified name, like: `new my.package.Process(....)`.

But I advise you to change the name, it will give your code more clarity.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that the built-in `java.lang.Process` class is `abstract`, so that probably also added to the confusion.